# Android Crashlytics error NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, crashlytics

I'm using Fabric in a non gradle based Android Studio project. Crashlytics was functioning perfect.
I now have the 2.2.0 plugin version and after I click in the plugin icon I can see that Crashlytics is installed.

When I run my app I'm getting the error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.`
You can see the stacktrace [here](http://pastebin.com/fF4aYs6D);

In the root of my project I have:

kit-libs folder with:

```
com-crashlytics-sdk-android_answers
com-crashlytics-sdk-android_beta
com-crashlytics-sdk-android_crashlytics
com-crashlytics-sdk-android_crashlytics-core
io-fabric-sdk-android_fabric
```

crashlytics.properties with the api secret

and kits.properties with this line: `com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.3.1

How can I solve this error?

Comment: http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/202938-gradle.

Comment: @Raghunandan Thanks but I can't configure my project to use gradle. Crachlytics was running fine in this non gradle project but now I'm getting the `NoClassDefFoundError` error